# sh: /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run: No such file or directory

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I am trying to install Oracle 11g database on my Mac machine, using Virtual box.
Getting below error while trying to install guest addition in Linux 6.4:

```
[root@Linux1 ~]# sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
sh: /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run: No such file or directory
[root@Linux1 ~]#
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Did you mount the Guest Addition CD from the Media dropdown menu?

Answer (score 1):

1. is /media/cdrom still mounted?
2. needs to be run in bash and also depends on build-essentials and linux-headers

I use unattended builds,  custom preseed.cfg replace late command. Change `mcs` to your username to add group to required user

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
    in-target apt-get -y install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) ; \
    in-target /bin/bash /media/cdrom/vboxadditions/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run --nox11 ; \
    in-target /bin/bash -c "udevadm constrol --reload-rules" ; \
    in-target /bin/bash -c "udevadm trigger" ; \
    in-target usermod -a -G vboxsf "mcs" ; \
```